# Ruby variables vs instance variables in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In Sinatra you can declare variables in two ways; either:

```
get '/' do
    var = 5
end
```

or

```
get '/' do
    @var = 5
end
```

Why use one or the other?

Also, shouldn't you technically not be able to use `@`, since it is not within a class, therefore an instance variable does not make sense?

Comment: so if you are able to access to `var` variable outside of `:get` handler, it says that `:get` handler is the closure. and it is expected behaviour. in second case `@var` becomes instance variable of `main` class instance. So it is expected behaviour too.

Comment: @majioa I don't understand your comment, can you rephrase please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables are setted on object, you are right.

But you can use them also on classes for example, because they are also objects. This might be hard to understand, but in ruby everything is an object, so because of that you can set instance variables everywhere (almost?).

When you call sinatra 'get' method. You are passing a block that should be run inside an object context. That you can later use inside your views for example.

```
get '/' do
  @var = 5
end
```

I'm not sure which one you should use, I would stick with instance @variables if you need them in the view, and local variables if you just want to use them inside the action/route

Comment: so essentially normal variables are restrained to the block while @variables can be used inside views?

Comment: Where would you *not* be able to set a instance variable, just out of curiosity?

Comment: For what I can remember you should be able to use it everywhere.

Comment: If that is the case, how is it distinguished from regular variables? Is it just a larger scope?

Comment: @Aristides: Instance variables are set on an object. The top level is in the context of a special object called "main" (you can see this by writing "puts self" at the top level). Some object is always self, so you can always set instance variables, though obviously any ivars you set won't be visible from other objects.